# Can't copy from HDFS to S3A

Tags: java, hadoop, amazon-s3, hdfs

I have a class to copy directory content from one location to another using [Apache FileUtil](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileUtil.html):

```java
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileStatus;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocatedFileStatus;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.RemoteIterator;

class Folder {
    private final FileSystem fs;
    private final Path pth;

    // ... constructors and other methods

    /**
     * Copy contents (files and files in subfolders) to another folder.
     * Merges overlapping folders
     * Overwrites already existing files
     * @param destination Folder where content will be moved to
     * @throws IOException If fails
     */
    public void copyFilesTo(final Folder destination) throws IOException {
        final RemoteIterator<LocatedFileStatus> iter = this.fs.listFiles(
            this.pth,
            true
        );
        final URI root = this.pth.toUri();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            final Path source = iter.next().getPath();
            FileUtil.copy(
                this.fs,
                source,
                destination.fs,
                new Path(
                    destination.pth,
                    root.relativize(source.toUri()).toString()
                ),
                false,
                true,
                this.fs.getConf()
            );
        }
    }
}
```

This class is working fine with local (`file:///`) directories in a unit test,
but when I'm trying to use it in Hadoop cluster to copy files from HDFS (`hdfs:///tmp/result`) to Amazon S3 (`s3a://mybucket/out`) it doesn't copy anything and doesn't throw error, just silently skip copying.

When I'm using same class (with both HDFS or S3a filesystems) for another purpose it's working fine, so the configuration and `fs` reference should be OK here.

What I'm doing wrong? How to copy files from HDFS to S3A correctly?

I'm using `Hadoop 2.7.3`.

---

**UPDATE**
I've added more logs to `copyFilesTo` method to log `root`, `source` and `target` variables (and extracted `rebase()` method without changing the code):

```java
    /**
     * Copy contents (files and files in subfolders) to another folder.
     * Merges overlapping folders
     * Overwrites already existing files
     * @param dst Folder where content will be moved to
     * @throws IOException If fails
     */
    public void copyFilesTo(final Folder dst) throws IOException {
        Logger.info(
            this, "copyFilesTo(%s): from %s fs=%s",
            dst, this, this.hdfs
        );
        final RemoteIterator<LocatedFileStatus> iter = this.hdfs.listFiles(
            this.pth,
            true
        );
        final URI root = this.pth.toUri();
        Logger.info(this, "copyFilesTo(%s): root=%s", dst, root);
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            final Path source = iter.next().getPath();
            final Path target = Folder.rebase(dst.path(), this.path(), source);
            Logger.info(
                this, "copyFilesTo(%s): src=%s target=%s",
                dst, source, target
            );
            FileUtil.copy(
                this.hdfs,
                source,
                dst.hdfs,
                target,
                false,
                true,
                this.hdfs.getConf()
            );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Change the base of target URI to new base, using root
     * as common path.
     * @param base New base
     * @param root Common root
     * @param target Target to rebase
     * @return Path with new base
     */
    static Path rebase(final Path base, final Path root, final Path target) {
        return new Path(
            base, root.toUri().relativize(target.toUri()).toString()
        );
    }
```

After running in the cluster I've got these logs:

```
io.Folder: copyFilesTo(hdfs:///tmp/_dst): from hdfs:///tmp/_src fs=DFS[DFSClient[clientName=DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_182008924_1, ugi=hadoop (auth:SIMPLE)]]
io.Folder: copyFilesTo(hdfs:///tmp/_dst): root=hdfs:///tmp/_src
INFO io.Folder: copyFilesTo(hdfs:///tmp/_dst): src=hdfs://ip-172-31-2-12.us-east-2.compute.internal:8020/tmp/_src/one.file target=hdfs://ip-172-31-2-12.us-east-2.compute.internal:8020/tmp/_src/one.file
```

I localized the wrong code in `rebase()` method, it's not working correctly when running in EMR cluster because `RemoteIterator` is returning URIs in remote format:  `hdfs://ip-172-31-2-12.us-east-2.compute.internal:8020/tmp/_src/one.file` but this method is expecting format `hdfs:///tmp/_src/one.file`, this is why it's working locally with `file:///` FS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that it's the best and fully correct solution, but it's working for me. The idea is to fix host and port of local paths before rebasing, the working `rebase` method will be:

```java
    /**
     * Change the base of target URI to new base, using root
     * as common path.
     * @param base New base
     * @param root Common root
     * @param target Target to rebase
     * @return Path with new base
     * @throws IOException If fails
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("PMD.DefaultPackage")
    static Path rebase(final Path base, final Path root, final Path target)
        throws IOException {
        final URI uri = target.toUri();
        try {
            return new Path(
                new Path(
                    new URIBuilder(base.toUri())
                        .setHost(uri.getHost())
                        .setPort(uri.getPort())
                        .build()
                ),
                new Path(
                    new URIBuilder(root.toUri())
                        .setHost(uri.getHost())
                        .setPort(uri.getPort())
                        .build()
                        .relativize(uri)
                )
            );
        } catch (final URISyntaxException err) {
            throw new IOException("Failed to rebase", err);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything obviously wrong.

1. Does it do hdfs-hdfs or s3a-s3a?
2. Upgrade your hadoop version; 2.7.x is woefully out of date, especially with the S3A code. It's unlikely to make whatever this problem go away, but it will avoid other issues. Once you've upgraded, switch to the [fast upload](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/#Stabilizing:_S3A_Fast_Upload) and it will do incremental updates of large files; currently your code will be saving each file to /tmp somewhere and then uploading it in the close() call.
3. turn on the logging for the org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a module and see what it says

Comment: Thanks for answer. 1). it doesn't work for hdfs-to-s3a and hdfs-to-hdfs modes, but is working for local-to-local. 2) upgrading will be quite expensive for project, since it's using Apache Nutch 1.7 as a dependency 3) will start it with `DEBUG` logging and update the question

Comment: I've answered with a workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57574695/1723695 if you know better solution for this problem I'm ready to accept your answer.